# Let other class know when data finished downloading

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a separate class which gets called from my main view controller and starts downloading json data and parsing it into an array (instance variable) asynchronously

is there any way I can notify my view controller once this data has finished downloading completely and pass this array back?

ive tried using a few loops and sleep timers in my viewdidload method to wait for data to be downloaded, but this didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use delegates for this purpose. Just google to find details about delegates. Here is a simple [tutorial](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/).

Basic idea, is to pass a handle of your main view controller to your subclass and the subclass will inform the mainview controller after processing json and send back the results to mainview controller using delegate.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think delegates is useful this purpose but the better option is the block api use for the better way I write this code.
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{

```
              // data downloading
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

              // downloading data use

        });
    });
```

Hopes this is help full for u.

Answer (score 0):

Use Notification Center pattern.

When the data is downloaded then notify the ViewController through the notification pattern.

For Example.

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SampleNotification" object:arrayObject];

Add this code into the data json parsing class and Pass the Array object.

Add the below code into the ViewController class. To get the Array object.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(smapleMethod:) name:@"SampleNotification" object:nil];

-(void)smapleMethod:(NSNotification *)notification{

```
 NSString * message=notification.object;
NSLog(@"Message =%@",message);
```

}